# How to loop through 1 to 5 in thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to loop through 1 to 5 in the thymeleaf, similar to jsp code:

```
<c: forEach begin = "1" end = "5" varStatus = "V"> </ c: forEach>.
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
<th:block th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1, 5)}"></th:block>
```

Comment: Has been resolved, but if the 5 replaced with a variable, how to do?

Comment: just replace 5 with the variable.  for example, `<th:block th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1, variable)}"></th:block>`

Comment: @Metroids was looking for this comment. Thanks