# Thymeleaf iteration with a specific integer, but not using an array size or index

Tags: iteration, thymeleaf

Does anyone know if it's possible using thymeleaf templates to iterate with a specific numerical value that does not come from the index or the size of an array? 
For example:
 for(i=0;i<4;i++).
So something similar to a for loop and yes I have looked at the thymeleaf docs. 
Thanks in advance!!

Hopefully this helps.  The form below will be used to take in a chemical name along with a few other details which are the other fields. I would like to repeat the form fields a specific number of times which is determined by the user. So if the user is asked "how many chemicals would you like to add to your list?" and the answer is 3 I would like to have the form fields repeat 3 times.

```
<form method="post" th:object="${reagent}">
    <div>
    <label th:for="chemName">Compound/Reagent</label>
    <input th:field="*{chemName}" />
    <span th:errors="*{chemName}"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label th:for="mw">Molecular Weight(g/mol)</label>
    <input th:field="*{mw}"/>
        <span th:errors="*{mw}"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label th:for="density">Density(g/L)</label>
    <input th:field="*{density}"/>
        <span th:errors="*{density}"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label th:for="hazard">Hazards</label>
    <textarea th:field="*{hazard}"></textarea><br/><br/>
        <span th:errors="*{hazard}"></span>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Chemical"/>
</form>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42218885/4126893

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through 1 to 5 in thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216529/how-to-loop-through-1-to-5-in-thymeleaf)